# Function spaces on manifolds via category theory

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, category-theory

In order to define function spaces on manifolds one usually follows the same recipe and this begs for a categorial formulation. I would like to know whether there is a reference that discusses this in some detail.

Here is an example of what I have in mind: Let $E$ be a function space on $\mathbb{R}^d$, say $E=L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ or some Sobolev space. Then for $U\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ define $E_c(U)$  to consist of restrictions to $U$ of elements in $E$ with support compactly contained in $U$. Then $E_c(U)$ admits a natural Frechet space structure and for the examples above any diffeo $U\cong V$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ induces an isomorphism $E_c(U)\cong E_c(V)$ of Frechet spaces (coordinate invariance).
Now if $M$ is a manifold, then one can define $E_c(U)$ whenever $U\subset M$ is a chart domain and for general $U$ via a partition of unity argument.

The two properties that allowed us to make the construction above are:
1) Elements of $E$ can be restricted, we can e.g. assume that $E$ embeds into the space of distributions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and use the natural restriction there.
2) The local spaces $E_c$ are coordinate invariant.

I assume that there the construction can be formalised in the following way: For any function space $E$ with the properties 1) and 2) there exists a functor $\mathcal E_c: \mathsf{Man}\rightarrow \mathsf{LCTVS}$ from the category of smooth manifolds to the category of locally convex topological spaces such that $\mathcal{E}_c(U) \cong E_c(U)$ in a natural way when $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$.  What I am interested in is whether this in turn gives rise to a functor $E \mapsto \mathcal{E}_c$ with nice properties, e.g preserving compact embeddings, exact sequences and so on.

One very concrete example that I am interested in occurs in the setting of pseudodifferential operators. On $\mathbb{R}^d$ they are easy to define and one proofs e.g. that the symbol map gives rise to a short exact sequence of Frechet spaces. The same result is true on closed manifolds and I believe that this should follow from abstract nonsense.

Comment: Are you familiar with *sheaves*?

Comment: With the basics yes. I guess a similar question I could have asked is when a sheaf on $\mathbb{R}^d$ extends to a functor on the category of manifolds and what functional analytic properties are preserved when considering sheaves taking values in LCTVS.  I suppose one should consider the corresponding $E_\mathrm{loc}$-spaces instead of the compactly supported ones to end up with a sheaf. One of the reasons why I avoided mentioning sheaves was that psido's can probably only be viewed as sheaves on the product space (via their Schwartz kernel)  and I thought this would complicate matters.

Comment: The thing is, if you start with a sheaf (or something that should be a sheaf), it's somewhat easier to get a sense of how you should define $\mathcal E_c(M)$ (as an equalizer over a covering by euclidean opens). The problem is that usually, things that have compact support do not form sheaves (for obvious reasons : if you have an increasing cover $U_n\subset U_{n+1}$ and every time a section which is define on some compact $K_n\subset U_n$ + some little compact subset of $U_{n+1}\setminus U_n$, then you won't, in general, be able to glue them)

Comment: So if you're especially interested in "blah with compact support", I don't think sheaves is the way to go. I don't know the answer to your question - on the one hand I feel like you're right and there should be some general abstract nonsense formalism, on the other hand , there is the problem that the solution should be wildly different from sheaves (to allow for "compactly supported blah", for instance over a compact manifold, this should give all "blah"'s, but you aren't allow to define them globally ! so that's something which seems hard to overcome), and I don't see how to solve that

Comment: I'm not very well-versed in functional analysis so I don't remember much : isn't $L^2(U)$ also Fréchet ? If it is, then maybe one possible alternative would be to define general blah's through something like sheaves, and then define compactly supported blah's in the obvious way, from the knowledge of what blah's are, so decompose your $E\mapsto \mathcal E_c$ as $E\mapsto \mathcal E \mapsto \mathcal E_c$ ?

Comment: Thanks, Maxime. The compact support is not so important for me, it is just one way how coordinate invariance is often phrased in an analysis context. One could equally well work with $E_\mathrm{loc}(U)$, defined as all distributions on $U$ which yield an element in $E$ after multiplying with a smooth cutoff, compactly supported in $U$. This should typically be Fréchet when the original space is (and yes, $L^2$ is a Hilbert space, so in particular Fréchet) and indeed $U\mapsto E_\mathrm{loc} (U)$ should be a sheaf.

Comment: For actual function spaces the sheaf approach is maybe the right one, although one probably has to be a bit careful, because as far as I understand the typical functional analytic categories are not abelian. Regarding pseudodifferential operators, I found [this] (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293384/do-pseudo-differential-operators-form-a-sheaf-of-algebras) MO question, which highlights some difficulties treating psido's as a sheaf. The composition issue I am less worried about, but the fact that it only works modulo residue classes or after sheafification gives me some headaches.